# How do I remove or reinstall Ubuntu in Windows 8 UEFI dual when Ubuntu is set as default?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I have a UEFI dual boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu, with GRUB set as the default boot manager.

I am looking to do a reinstall of Ubuntu since I accidentally did `apt-get remove` for some system packages. However, I cannot drop to root shell and do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` because it gives me a few errors saying that `critical dpkg config files are missing` or something like that.

If possible, I would just like to reinstall rather than remove and install, as this would save my files (the files have been backed up in a Windows 8 partition).

If I would need to reinstall, can I just remove the partition and then reinstall via DVD and Ubuntu GRUB would work, or would I have to set Windows 8 as my default UEFI boot manager?

Comment: I hope someone will correct me if i am wrong, but i thought that with the ubuntu install disc you can also repair a installation of Ubuntu. In that case your files would remain and your installation repaired so it is bootable again. For reinstallation you could remove the partition and reinstall, but you can also simply choose to reinstall from the Ubuntu install disc.
You can choose a new installation overwriting your old one. But i would try the repair option first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First backup your documents onto an external disk (USB or DVDs), then boot on your Ubuntu disk and follow [this procedure from the Community Documentation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation)